# Empty string need not be counted in python (repeat)

Tags: python

The purpose of the program is to count each word in a passage and note the frequency. Unfortunately, the program is also counting empty strings. My codes are:

```
def build_map( in_file, word_map ):
# Receives an input file and an empty dictionary


    for line in in_file:

    # Splits each line at blank space and turns it into
    # a list.
        word_list = line.split()



        for word in word_list: 
            word= word.strip().strip(string.punctuation).lower()#program revised           
            if word!='':

            # Within the word_list, we are stripping empty space
            # on both sides of each word and also stripping any
            # punctuation on both side of each word in the list.
            # Then, it turns each word to the lower case to avoid
            # counting 'THE' and 'the' as two different words.

                add_word( word_map, word)
```

I would really appreciate if someone could take a look at the codes and explain, why it is still counting empty strings. Other than that everything else is working fine. Thanks (modified the code and it is working fine now).

Comment: Define "word_map = collections.defaultdict(int)", then there is no need to initialize a new word to have count zero. I.e. every call to add_word can be replaced with word_map[word]+=1  You'll need to "import collections"

Comment: You should be able to replace the word_list variable within display_map with "word_map.items()" (and delete the first 3 lines of that function)

Comment: You could probably use counter from the collections module too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking if the word is empty and *then* you're stripping the whitespace and punctuation. Reverse the order of these operations.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for painstakingly going through my code and finding out the problem.